# Test Internet Explorer 8 with Google Chrome Frame?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a somewhat complex javascript-based UI-interface for a web app. Because of its complexity it's not going to be easy to make it fully compatible or degradable with IE8, so I plan to inform registered users who will be using this web app as a service to install Google chrome frame: http://www.google.com/chromeframe?quickenable=true - (and I hope this will help update IE8 and make it more like Chrome?) The thing is - on my machine I already have IE9 and need to keep it there, don't want to uninistall it. Is there any online way I can test IE8 *with the google chrome frame add-on*? I know about spoon and browsershots that let us see our webpage in IE8, but I need to see it with an IE8 that has **google chrome frame added on**. Any way to do this?

Comment: i go through the amazing process of installing native ie7-9 everytime i need test alot. emulators and vms are cool, but i've found bugs that they've missed. every.single.time. so your best bet is probably to just reinstall everytime

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft offers a bunch of virtual machines images for all their browser versions on different OS versions. You might be able to install Chrome frame addon into the IE8 version you want to test.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://www.browserstack.com/. It offers pretty much any browser / OS combination you would want to test.